# Text validation before storing into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, validation, text

it's about one day that I'm looking for a solution, however I don't have all the necessary skills to understand whether what I found is the right or solution or not.
So, in conclusion, what are the minimum validation that I have to do before storing a text, received by a post method, into an MySQL DB? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `PDO` (or `mysqli`) with prepared statements:

```
$st = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO test (x) VALUES (?)');
$st->execute(array($_POST['text']));
```

Done.

If you want to use the old mysql extension, you might want to use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead on all values you insert into the query.

Comment: What about the function trim, stripslashes and htmlspecialchars ? When do i need to use them and why in this case I don't?

Comment: `stripslashes` was something which was quite common in old times with a setting called `magic_quotes`. All $_GET/$_POST variables were "magically" escaped, if this was on. One does not need to use this function nowadays as `magic_quotes` is now off by default.

Comment: The other functions should be applied on *outputting* somthing. You should always store the original data into the database. Just think of if you make an error and store lots of wrong data in your database, because you call the functions on insertion already. This would be very bad. You would have to correct the whole database. If you call the functions on outputting, you can just change the calls and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');

//gets the post info
$text = $_POST['key'];    

//removes the white spaces before and after the string
$text = trim($text);      

// prepares the text for storing it in the database. Helps against MySQL injections.
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $text);
```

So these I think are the bare minimum. Also you need to check if the info that comes from the POST is valid. For example if you expect to receive number but text is received, you have to deal with these sort of problems.

Comment: if I want to enter a link, then?

Comment: Give some code that I can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The major concern while getting user input from web forms and storing it in to any db is the possibility of an sql injection. Using prepared statements (as suggested by GhostGambler) can help guard against SQL injection. As a minimum level of protection mysqli_real_escape_string should be used, however note it is not the best protection.
The mysql interface is deprecated so use either mysqli or pdo.
Prepared statements and parameterized queries provide decent protection against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are **filter_var** functions provided by php. Its the best bet. You can use the constants for checking whether a value is an Integer, or String or a proper email, etc.

Ex:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$filter_email=filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

It will return you false if the filter fails.

2. Then the best way you can insert the datas into ur DB is by using prepared statements. It almost eliminates the chances of SQL Injection.

You can read about prepared statements in here [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/mysqli_prepare)

3. You can also go for regular expressions

Hope this helps